# DeleteView with a dynamic success_url dependent on id

Tags: django

I have an app for posts, with a url for each post:

```
url(r'^post/(?P<id>\w+)/$', 'single_post', name='single_post'),
```

On each post, I have comments. I would like to be able to delete each comment from the post page and return to the post that I was on.

I have the following url for deleting comments:

```
    url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', CommentDelete.as_view(),
    name='comment_delete'),
```

And I know from previous research that I need override the get_success_url, but I'm not sure how to reference the post id that I was just on. I think I need to use kwargs, but not sure how. I have this currently, but it doesn't work...

```
class CommentDelete(PermissionMixin, DeleteView):
model = Comment
def get_success_url(self): 
    return reverse_lazy( 'single_post',
        kwargs = {'post.id': self.kwargs.get('post.id', None)},)
```

Ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should work:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    # Assuming there is a ForeignKey from Comment to Post in your model
    post = self.object.post 
    return reverse_lazy( 'single_post', kwargs={'post.id': post.id})
```

Django's `DeleteView` inherits from `SingleObjectMixin`, which contains the [`get_object` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object).

Comment: Thanks, that worked, with a minor change: return reverse_lazy('single_post', kwargs={'id': post.id})

Comment: You're right! I missed that, sorry. You're welcome. :)

Comment: It didn't work at first for me, just changed self.get_object() for self.object, since the first one tries to do the query and look for the deleted object in the DB, it seemed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using a custom delete view. It was fixed by adding a class variable (static variable). An extract:

```
# Using FormView since I need to customize more than I can do with the standard DeleteView
class MyDeleteView(generic.FormView):
    person_id = 0

    def get_success_url(self):
        # I cannot access the 'pk' of the deleted object here
        return reverse('person_identity', kwargs={'person_id': self.person_id})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        plan = get_object_or_404(Plan, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        self.person_id = plan.person_id 
        if form.cleaned_data.get('delete', False):
            Plan.objects.filter(person=plan.person, date__gte=plan.date)\
                .filter(date__gte=datetime.date.today())\
                .delete()
        return super(MyDeleteView, self).form_valid(form)
```