# Django: DeleteView pass argument from ForeignKey's Model to get_success_url

Tags: python, django

After the user deleted a PieceInstance I would like to redirect him to the Piece to which the PieceInstance belonged to. I use the default DeleteView and would like to pass the Piece id (Piece via PieceInstance referenced by ForeignKey) to the get_success_url method. `self.piece.pk` seems not to get the id of the corresponding Piece.

**models.py**

```
class PieceInstance(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this particular Piece across whole system')
    piece = models.ForeignKey('Piece', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True) 
    ...

class Piece(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
```

**views.py**

```
class PieceInstanceDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = PieceInstance
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('piece-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.piece.pk})
```

**urls.py**

```
path('piece/<int:pk>', views.PieceDetailView.as_view(), name='piece-detail')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the source code, the object is stored in `self.object` *before* it gets deleted. So you can redirect to the primary key of the related `piece` with:

```
class PieceInstanceDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = PieceInstance

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('piece-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.piece_id})
```

The problem however is that this is *undocumented*, and therefore it is possible that the Django view is later rewritten without such behavior.

In case this behavior no longer happens, it might be worth to patch the `delete` function:

```
#  probably not necessary, but there is no "contract" that the above will
#  always work

class PieceInstanceDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = PieceInstance

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('piece-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.piece_id})
```

Comment: thanks again for the clarification Willem. Could you point me somewhere regarding what you mean by undocumented?

Comment: @AaronScheib: what I mean is that a `CreateView`, and `UpdateView` have - as in the documentation - an `object` attribute (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView.object), that is not the case for a `DeleteView`, so that means that the developers of Django have the "freedom" to implement it the way they want. Yes, right now this set a `self.object` (https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.4/django.views.generic.edit/DeleteView/#delete) but they can easily change their  mind.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you for post, it was very helpful. I patched the `delete` function as per your instructions but kept getting the following error: `DeleteView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.` Turns out making `delete` actually returning the super call solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

got it using this answer:
[DeleteView with a dynamic success_url dependent on id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290415/deleteview-with-a-dynamic-success-url-dependent-on-id/26291235)

**here the DeleteView class:**

```
class PieceInstanceDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = PieceInstance
    def get_success_url(self):
        piece = self.object.piece
        return reverse_lazy('piece-detail', kwargs={'pk': piece.pk})
```