# I am trying to delete a comment with dynamic success url in my Django Project but it gives me a 404

Tags: django, django-views

So The code for this view is
My Models, Urls and everything is fine and I event went to check for the data I am requesting manually and funny enough it appeared there.
Can someone tell me what mistake is there?

```
class CommentDeleteView(OwnerDeleteView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = "ads/comment_delete.html"

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290415/deleteview-with-a-dynamic-success-url-dependent-on-id
    def get_success_url(self):
        ad = self.object.ad
        ctx={'ad':ad.id}
        return reverse_lazy('ads:ad_detail', ctx)
```

[image: Image of the 404 error]

Comment: Show me your redirected url that are in your template. The one that you click and throws this error.

Comment: I dont Understand what are you saying?

Comment: I don't get what you're doing in the `get_success_url`. You just deleted the `Comment object` in your view, then after deleting it you want to access it in the `get_success_url`? That shouldn't work as you just deleted it. Or, am I not understanding your code?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the generic views in Django to delete the comment.

```
from django.views.generic import DeleteView
```

and then simply using the code as follow

```
class CommentDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = "ads/comment_delete.html"
```

after this you can edit your `urls.py` file as

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
url_patterns = [
        path('your path' , views.CommentDeleteView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('the path you are directing to')) , name = 'ad_comment_delete']
```

Comment: I'm already doing that. The owner file is already doing that with some changes like only the owner of a comment or ad can delete it using django Auth.

Comment: @RaffeyGamer what you mean by owner file?